# How can I use N number of cores to constantly run the same set of functions(in parallel) in python, without locking any particular core to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have 10 different functions that I would like to run endlessly in parallel over 4 cores.
Each function runs for a different amount of time and would like all 4 cores to be in use all the time.

How can I set things up so that whenever a core is free, it pops a job from the queue, completes it and adds it back to the end of the queue?

Comment: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck? There is a native `multiprocessing.Queue` you can use directly for the queue you described, and run a loop in each process to grab and execute tasks.

Comment: This question is far too vague; that is, underspecified. Too, as @Aaron asked, what have you tried?